# Number of reads for multiple Firebase trigger functions doing similar things

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an `onUpdate` firestore trigger function that does multiple things:

```
functions.firestore.document('document').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const updatedObject = change.after.data()
  if (updatedObject.first) {
    doFirst()
  }
  if (updatedObject.second) {
    doSecond()
  }
})
```

I am thinking of splitting this trigger into 2 smaller triggers to keep my functions more concise.

```
functions.firestore.document('document').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const updatedObject = change.after.data()
  if (!updatedObject.first) {
    return
  }
  doFirst()
})

functions.firestore.document('document').onUpdate((change, context) => {
  const updatedObject = change.after.data()
  if (!updatedObject.second) {
    return
  }
  doSecond()
})
```

The [firestore pricing docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) mentions the following:

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)

*Would this increase the number of reads from 1 to 2?*
The docs does not clearly state the behavior when there are multiple functions listening to the same event.

A more general question I have is *would increasing the number of functions listening to the same event increase the number of reads and hence increase my bill?*

*Is there a best practice for this issue?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The document data passed to Cloud Functions as part of the trigger (so `change.before` and `change.after`) comes out of the existing flow, and is not a charged read. Only additional reads that you perform *inside* your Cloud Functions code would be charged.